# Filter table rows linked to another table via pivot table on basis of where clauses acting on second table

Tags: mysql, orm, knex.js, bookshelf.js

```
+--------------+
|  paintings   |
+--------------+
| id | title   |
+----+---------+
| 1  | muzelf1 |
| 2  | muzelf2 |
| 3  | muzelf3 |
+----+---------+

+----------------------------------------+
|                  tags                  |
+----------------------------------------+
| id | type            | name            |
+----+-----------------+-----------------+
| 1  | painting_medium | oil_painting    |
| 2  | painting_style  | impressionistic |
| 3  | painting_medium | mixed_media     |
| 4  | painting_medium | watercolours    |
| 5  | painting_style  | mixed_media     |
| 6  | painting_style  | photorealistic  |
+----+-----------------+-----------------+


+---------------------------+
|       paintings_tags      |
+---------------------------+
| id | painting_id | tag_id |
+----+-------------+--------+
| 1  | 1           | 1      |
| 2  | 1           | 2      |
| 3  | 2           | 4      |
| 4  | 3           | 2      |
| 5  | 3           | 1      |
+----+-------------+--------+
```

sql

```
CREATE TABLE paintings (
id integer AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
title text
);

INSERT INTO paintings(id,title) VALUES
 (1,'muzelf1'),(2,'muzelf2'),(3,'muzelf3');

CREATE TABLE tags (
id integer AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
name text,
type text
);

INSERT INTO tags(id,name,type) VALUES
(1,'oil_painting','painting_medium')
,(2,'impressionistic','painting_style')
,(3,'mixed_media','painting_medium')
,(4,'watercolours','painting_medium')
,(5,'mixed_media','painting_style')
,(6,'photorealistic','painting_style');

CREATE TABLE paintings_tags (
id integer AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
painting_id integer,
tag_id integer
);

INSERT INTO paintings_tags(id,painting_id,tag_id) VALUES
(1,1,1)
,(2,1,2)
,(3,2,4)
,(4,3,2)
,(5,3,1);
```

> Find all the paintings with [{tags.type="painiting_medium", tags.name="oil_painitng"},{tags.type="painiting_style", tags.name="impressionistic"}].

```
+-----------------------------------+
|         Expected Output           |
+-----------------------------------+
| id | painting_title | painting_id |
+----+----------------+-------------+
| 1  | muzelf1        | 1           |
+----+----------------+-------------+
| 2  | muzelf3        | 3           |
+----+----------------+-------------+
```

Here is something I tried doing using *bookShelf ORM* and *knex query builder*.

```
 Painting.query(function (qb) {
    qb.innerJoin('painting_tags','paintings.id','painting_tags.painting_id')
            .innerJoin('tags','painting_tags.tag_id','tags.id')
            .where(qb => {
              tagFilters.forEach(filter => {
                qb.where('tags.type',filter.type).andWhere('tags.name',filter.name)
              })
            });
    });
```

The above only works if the tag filters array has only one element. But I need it to work for all the filters in the array.

> What would a raw query look like for the above? And how can I convert the same to work using ORM and query builder?

Comment: Although there is an argument for handling all the filtering in application code, e.g.: https://isotope.metafizzy.co/filtering.html

Comment: @Strawberry okay. Can you help me with the query then?

Comment: @Strawberry actually I did provide a sample db structure and corresponding sample table content. Do you want me to format the above in the form of tables.

Comment: Okay, so I think I formatted the question the way you asked @Strawberry. Do you think you can help me now?

Comment: @Strawberry I have provided the create and insert queries too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one idea:

```
SELECT p.id painting_id
     , p.title
     , MAX(CASE WHEN t.type = 'painting_medium' THEN t.name END) medium
     , MAX(CASE WHEN t.type = 'painting_style' THEN t.name END) style 
  FROM paintings p 
  JOIN paintings_tags pt 
    ON pt.painting_id = p.id 
  JOIN tags t 
    ON t.id = pt.tag_id 
 GROUP 
    BY p.id;
+-------------+---------+--------------+-----------------+
| painting_id | title   | medium       | style           |
+-------------+---------+--------------+-----------------+
|           1 | muzelf1 | oil_painting | impressionistic |
|           2 | muzelf2 | watercolours | NULL            |
|           3 | muzelf3 | oil_painting | impressionistic |
+-------------+---------+--------------+-----------------+
```

You could filter this as a subquery (or using HAVING) but, unless the data set was vast, I would be inclined to do the filtering in a bit of javascript.

Comment: I would but I have to paginate the data too. Do you propose I make the pagination data too in jafascript?

Comment: Again, unless the data set is unmanageble (i.e. performance noticeably starts to suffer), I would spit the results out as json and do all pagination and filtering in javascript.